Problems installing image packages for javascript application
I am following the course from Johnatan Mircha for Node.js in this video. I am developing the final application at the end of the video for the optimization of image files. However, when installing the packages in the devDependencies of the package.json,
{
  "name": "imgopt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Creando una app en Node.js para optimizar imágenes para la web",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jonathan MirCha",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "imagemin": "^8.0.1",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.2",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^10.0.1",
    "imagemin-webp": "^8.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.4"
  }
}

I am obtaining the following error
npm error code 1
npm error path /media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm error sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.14.5/libvips-8.14.5-linux-x64.tar.br
npm error sharp: Integrity check passed for linux-x64
npm error
npm error make: Entering directory '/media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp/build'
npm error   CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
npm error rm -f Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a.ar-file-list; mkdir -p `dirname Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a`
npm error ar crs Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a @Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a.ar-file-list
npm error   COPY Release/nothing.a
npm error   TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
npm error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp-linux-x64/src/common.o
npm error make: Leaving directory '/media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp/build'
npm error sh: 1: prebuild-install: Permission denied
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@20.16.0 | linux | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.8 found at "/home/juanessao2000/anaconda3/bin/python3"
npm error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.16.0/node-v20.16.0-headers.tar.gz
npm error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.16.0/node-v20.16.0-headers.tar.gz
npm error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm error gyp info spawn /home/juanessao2000/anaconda3/bin/python3
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args '/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/home/juanessao2000/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/juanessao2000/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/juanessao2000/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp info spawn make
npm error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm error ../src/common.cc:13:10: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
npm error    13 | #include <vips/vips8>
npm error       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm error compilation terminated.
npm error make: *** [sharp-linux-x64.target.mk:138: Release/obj.target/sharp-linux-x64/src/common.o] Error 1
npm error gyp ERR! build error 
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
npm error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-117-generic
npm error gyp ERR! command "/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/bin/node" "/home/juanessao2000/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd /media/juanessao2000/hdd/PRINCIPAL-2023-2/CURSOS/JohnatanMircha/Node_js/05_Proyectos/ImgOpt/node_modules/sharp
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v20.16.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/juanessao2000/.npm/_logs/2024-08-05T02_43_13_229Z-debug-0.log

I tried installing each package individually but still I get problems with the installing. I have been searching for other developers questions in case someone else has had the same problem but I have not found anything that works for me.
Any advice on this installing would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1882

By what Robby commented it seems, that installing minipass package could help you, try something like this:
"dependencies": {
  "minipass": "7.1.2",
  "sharp": "^0.32.4"
}

or put it in dev-dependencies and try again
